# "Convert to try-with-resources" in Netbeans - Cool Beans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have the following code in Netbeans 7.1.2:

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
bos.write(newRawData);
bos.close();
```

A warning suggests that I "convert to try-with-resources." When I choose to do this, my code becomes:

```
try (BufferedOutputStream bufferedFos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))) {
        bufferedFos.write(newRawData);
    }
```

This looks similar to the syntax for using(...) in C#... do they work the same way? Is there any downside to using this second format? I'm worried about the absence of `bos.close();`, but is it simply not necessary with this format?

Comment: The try with resources block will close any resource that are opened in the `try(..)` block. I would take a look at the oracle documentation to understand it better: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was a new syntax that was introduced in Java 7, which takes care of closing any resources you specify when declaring the `try(...)` statement. More info can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html).
So no, you don't have to do a `bos.close()`, it is performed by Java. You can just sit back and relax.
The only downside is that your code works with Java 7+ only.

Answer (score 5):

### Note

The "try with resources" statement was [introduced in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as a replacement for the `try...finally` statement. Basically, all it does is keep you from having to add:

```
finally {
  if(resource != null) resource.close();
}
```

to the end of your `try` statement. If you use this, your code will only work with Java 7 and up.

## Answer

`try` is part of a statement in Java called `try...catch`. A full solution to the warning you were given would be:

```
try(BufferedOutputStream bufferedFos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))) {
  bufferedFos.write(newRawData);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A "try with resources" block uses the same structure as the `try...catch` block, but automatically closes any resources that are created inside the block once it has been executed. That's why you don't see a `bufferedFos.close();` statement in the code.

Comment: For many resources it keeps you from having to add `finally { if ( resource != null ) { try { resource.close();} catch ( Exception e ) {}}}` which is even uglier (especially since it's not formatted in comments.)

Comment: Slight correction : closes any resources that are created inside the ***parentheses that precede the*** code block.